# Setting default DateTimeFormat Annotation in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datetime-format, spring-annotations

I know that a DateTimeFormat annotation can be defined on Date properties of a Model class in Spring but is there any way of defining a default dateTimeFormat annotation for all Dates in Spring Model classes?

> @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/YYYY")
>   private Date
>   deliveryDate;

It will save me from annotating each date field. It will also make it easy for me to change the application wide date format later on.

Comment: You can create a custom annotation that helps to parse date to your default format. However, you must add your custom annotation on Date properties at least

Answer (score 3):

As kuhajeyan mentioned, you can use binder, but not on a controller, rather on controller advice, that will apply it globally:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalDateBinder {

 /* Initialize a global InitBinder for dates*/

 @InitBinder
 public void binder(WebDataBinder binder) {
  // here you can use kuhajeyan's code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your controller

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(
            dateFormat, false));
}
```