# How to globally configure `@DateTimeFormat` pattern in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Im my Spring Boot application, I have some controllers that accept a date as query parameter:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

  @GetMapping
  public ResponseEntity<?> getDataByDate(
      @RequestParam(value = "date") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
      final LocalDate date) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok();
  }
}
```

This works well, and I can even mark the parameter as optional using `@RequestParam(value = "date", required = false)` and then use an `Optional<LocalDate>`. Spring will handle all this and pass an empty Optional when the parameter is missing.

Since I have several controllers using dates as query parameters, I want to configure this behavior for all `LocalDate` query parameters. I have tried the `spring.mvc.date-pattern` property, but it only seems to work for `java.util.Date`.

So after searching the web, the best I came up with is a `ControllerAdvice` I adopted from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726183/5391954). The problem with this solution is, that is can not handle `Optional<LocalDate>` anymore. It feels like this is the wrong way to configure the behavior in Spring Boot.

So my question is: How do I globally configure the pattern for `LocalDate` used as query parameters in an idiomatic way in Spring Boot?

Comment: That looks like the way to do it globally using a ControllerAdvice. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40644368/setting-default-datetimeformat-annotation-in-spring.

Comment: As I said, this solution does not handle `Optional<LocalDate>` and it does not feel idiomatic to me. There should be some configuration property to easily set this.

Comment: It looks like this it not easily possible. See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5523

Comment: so you could implement `org.springframework.core.convert.converter.GenericConverter` and doing the conversion yourself

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is currently not easily possible (e.g. by setting a simple configuration property), see [#5523](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5523). The best solution I found so far is to register a `Formatter<LocalDate>`. This will also work with optional parameters modeled as `Optional<LocalDate>`:

```
  @Bean
  public Formatter<LocalDate> localDateFormatter() {
    return new Formatter<LocalDate>() {
      @Override
      public LocalDate parse(String text, Locale locale) throws ParseException {
        return LocalDate.parse(text, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
      }

      @Override
      public String print(LocalDate object, Locale locale) {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(object);
      }
    };
  }
```

It may become possible to set this using a configuration property when my proposal in [#9930](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/9930) has been merged.

Comment: I've written a blog post about this: https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2017/08/parsing-of-localdate-query-parameters-in-spring-boot/

Answer (score 4):

You can use [spring.mvc.format.date](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.mvc.format.date), `spring.mvc.format.time` and `spring.mvc.format.date-time`

For example:
`spring.mvc.format.time=HH:mm:ss`
`spring.mvc.format.date=iso`
`spring.mvc.format.date-time=iso-offset`

as in the example above, you can use shortcuts `iso` аnd `iso-offset` from spring boot 2.4.1

Answer (score 2):

@britter: thanks.

`spring.mvc.date-format= # Date format to use. For instance, dd/MM/yyyy` works fine with
Spring Boot 2.1.0.x

See [# SPRING MVC (WebMvcProperties)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) properties.

UPDATE: But it doen't work for Spring Data Rest params ...